# Initialize private static const vector<vector<string> > class member

Tags: c++, vector

The keywords here are multidimensional and `string`.

I have two different multidimensional arrays that are both `static const vector<vector<T> >` but one is an `int` vector and the other is a `string` vector. I have no problems initializing the `int` vector `fooGroups` but the `string` vector `barGroups` gives me fits.

Nothing that I've found at this point addresses all of these things combined in a way that fixes my problem since even `vector<string> tGroups` worked properly when I tested to make sure it wasn't the type that was throwing it off.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class T {
    private:
        static const std::vector<std::string> tGroups;
        static const std::vector<std::vector<int> > fooGroups;
        static const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > barGroups;
};

const std::vector<std::string> T::tGroups = {
    "blah","blah","blah","blah"
};

const std::vector<std::vector<int> > T::fooGroups = {
    //L0, L1, L2, ...
    {0,0,15},
    {0,0,6},
    {0,0,4}
};

const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > T::barGroups = {
    {"blah","blah"},
    {"blah","blah","blah","blah"},
    {"blah","blah","blah"}
};
```

The error reads:

```
26|error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >, std::allocator<std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
```

Comment: [works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4abe53544baa393) what compiler/version are you using?

Comment: No issues here too:  http://ideone.com/urlQlQ.  Also no issues compiling and linking with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: It seems your standard library have incomplete support for C++11 initializer lists.

Comment: I'm baffled, but after gnawing on this long enough to resort to reinstalling Visual Studio it worked. *throws up hands* Apparently, my recent install has been faulty this entire time. Imagine that. No wonder I've despised having to work on my non-production machine (for more than the obvious reasons). 0_o)